# Need access to raw spreadsheet file on Google drive for import into Matlab

Tags: matlab, google-drive-api

I have access to a .xlsx or .csv copy of the data. These files are on Google Drive as they pretty much have to be.

I can't  web, urlread, urlwrite, websave, or anything with this data as even with a direct link such as

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifCZkfO5ZfI2tb6JziU2HooZ4MLQeWpPStYGtXWfZ3g/pub?output=xlsx
```

it doesn't give me the raw file. It gives me html and javascript to go along with it. Is there a way to acquire the pure file on google drive so as it can be imported?

Answer (score 0):

You first have to save the file to your hard-drive

```
websave('data.xlsx', 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifCZkfO5ZfI2tb6JziU2HooZ4MLQeWpPStYGtXWfZ3g/pub?output=xlsx');
```

Afterwards, you can read it as usual:

```
[NUM,TXT,RAW] = xlsread('data.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', 'A:AD');
```